# Swift - Protocol default implementation in extension with generic superclass constraint

Tags: swift, generics, constraints, protocols

I am trying to constraint a protocol extension to a generic class. My goal is to provide a default implementation of a protocol where Self is any instance that is subclass of some generic class. Consider the below example:

```
protocol Printable {
  var value: String { get }
}

class Printer<P: Printable> {
  let printable: P
  init(printable: P) {
    self.printable = printable
  }
}

protocol Press {
  func print()
}

// error: reference to generic type 'Printer' requires arguments in <...>

extension Press where Self: Printer {
  func print() {
    // Do Something with self.printable.value
  }
}
```

The compiler gives error `error: reference to generic type 'Printer' requires arguments in <...>`.
I don't understand why this should not be allowed. As long as `Press` is some kind of `Printer` which always works with some kind of `Printable` things should work, right? Or I am missing something?

Can you point what could be the right way of achieving something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `Printer<A>` and `Printer<B>` are different types, even A & B are Printable, so due to possible ambiguity compiler generate error.

You need the following (tested with Xcode 11.4)

```
extension Press {
  func print<P>() where Self: Printer<P>, P: Printable {
    // Do Something with self.printable.value
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `P: Printable`, it can be inferred.

Comment: @Sweeper, yes, but it gives better interface readability, and not harmful, and Apple prefers such interface notation in their API. But yes, again, you're right - it can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, this works like a charm. I should have guessed it though.